# Automatically scroll down mat dialog

Tags: angular, angular-material

I use a modal MatDialog that comes from the material library. The last element in the modal is a  `<mat-expansion-panel>` element.

When the user clicks on this element (`<mat-expansion-panel>`)  to display its content, I would like he not to have to scroll down the modal manually. The desired behavior is that the modal scrolls automatically to display all the content of the `<mat-expansion-panel>`.

I borrowed the code in [this Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-auto-scroll-gkyykf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)
But it doesn't work in my project.

Here's my project code: HTML

```html
<div class="container" #scrollframe>
  <div class="container__justif-import">
    <mat-accordion>
      <mat-expansion-panel
        (opened)="panelOpenState = true"
        (closed)="panelOpenState = false"
      >
        <mat-expansion-panel-header>
          <mat-panel-title
            ><div (click)="scrollToBottom()">open</div></mat-panel-title
          >
        </mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <div>
          <p>blabla</p>
          <p>blabla</p>
          <p>blabla</p>
          <p>blabla</p>
          <p>blabla</p>
          <p>blabla</p>
        </div>
      </mat-expansion-panel>
    </mat-accordion>
  </div>
</div>
```

TS code:

```
export class myModalComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('scrollframe', { static: false }) scrollFrame?: ElementRef;
  
  public panelOpenState = false;

  public scrollContainer: any;
  
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.scrollContainer = this.scrollFrame?.nativeElement;
  }

  scrollToBottom(): void {
    this.scrollContainer.scroll({
      top: this.scrollContainer.scrollHeight,
      left: 0,
      behavior: 'smooth'
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Given the code you provided and the Stackblitz you have used it might be something with your styling. I tried to take your code and use it in the Stackblitz, it worked fine when I updated the class to the classes in the Stackblitz